# Is there any way I can keep GCM with Firebase SDK v3.3?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Someone please help me on this.

We have the application in production with the GCM implementation. We decided to update the Firebase SDK to 3.3 (which has the FIRMessaging  and FirebaseAnalytics implementation in it).

While working on the Firebase SDK upgrade we have changed the Podfile and and we are able to install the new Firebase v3.3 frameworks.

But when I try to compile the project its throwing several errors.

These are the last two line I got from the error,

```
ld: 44 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can see the error are due to the duplicate implementation between GCM and Firebase.

The real issue is I can't remove either of these framework. I need Google framework for GCM messaging. And I want Firebase 3.3 for the upgrade.

Any idea guys?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google rebranded GCM to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)  and it now offers cross platform service. Firebase also offers [notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/).

FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

FCM supports everything that you’ve come to know with Google Cloud Messaging including addressing single devices, groups of devices or topics.

To upgrade from GCM SDKs to FCM SDKs, please see the guides for migrating [iOS client apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm).